# What is the difference between "Plural" and "Mehrzahl"?

Tags: difference, grammatical-number

What's the difference between "Plural" and "Mehrzahl" (and "Singular"/"Einzahl")? The dictionaries I've seen don't give much detail, except that Mehrzahl might be less common.

Comment: "Plural" is the grammatical terminology. Mehrzahl means most likely "plural", but I never heard it in a grammatical context. I think it might be some similar like "Zukunft" (future) or "futur" (grammatical term).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Plural** is a Latin term, **die Mehrzahl** is the equivalent German term.

However, this only applies when discussing grammar, as the noun *die Mehrzahl* has other uses as well.

> In der Mehrzahl der Fälle verlaufen Infektionen mild.

It means *majority* then. You cannot use *Plural* in those cases. The counter term is *die Minderzahl*, as opposed to *die Einzahl* when discussing the *singular* grammar term.

Comment: Thanks! Which style would be more useful in the context of e.g. a grammar book?

Comment: The Latin terms because they aren't used in other contexts. Some people disagreed in the past as pupils had been *required* to learn Latin to understand German grammar, but *duh!* it's just random names, who cares if this was Latin or Moonspeak?

Comment: Similarly, we use either teh German term *Hauptwort* for *noun*, or the latin *Nomen* or the latin *Substantiv*; for *verb*, we either use latin *Verb* or German *Tuwort* or German *Zeitwort*. If you live through several phases of different didactical philosphies, this may become confusing ... I suppose that this abundance of differnt terms for the same also leads to many people confusing related terms between word types and parts of speech and think these are just one more name for the same thing (e.g., they may think *Adjektiv* = *Attiribut*, *Verb* = *Prädikat*, ...)

Comment: To specifically talk about the non-grammatical meaning, _Mehrheit_ can be used to mean only "majority", and never "plural" (you could say _in der Mehrheit der Fälle_).